# Why in TFS I cannot apply a label on files listed in Changeset Details window?

Tags: tfs, label, changeset, tfvc

As in subject:

1. Go to "Find Changeset" option.
2. Find a changeset.
3. Double-click on changeset to open Changeset Details window.
4. It gives a list of all files that have been checked in within given changeset.

Why I cannot apply a label on those files from that level where I have them all in one place? Especially, that very often they are part of different solutions and projects, so normally I would have to create a label for one file and then search and add one by one to the existing one. 
It is so inefficient!

Is it some bug or lack of functionality? If the second - it is hard to believe MS guys forgot about such handy function.
How do you deal guys with such situation?

**EDIT - to clarify my reasoning:**

If I use ***jessehouwing***'s method - yes, it works and it's simple.
But then when I search in the future for that label and want to see what code was included, it gives me a list of all solutions - even those totally unrelated (IWP and PDPRO are the unwanted ones):

[image]

If I use it my way - it gives me that:

[image]

I think it looks cleaner and gives directly the information of what solutions and files underneath where included at the time when I put stuff into Production environment and applied corresponding PROD label.

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a label for the whole branch or repository at that changeset number?

Comment: Please, have a look on my edits. Apologies for delayed answer - I've been away.

Comment: I'm afraid that what you want can't easily be accomplished. You can suggest an improvement here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: I have voted Up for your post as it still simplifies the process. I have also marked it as answer. Even though it doesn't solve the problem - it answers the question. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for doesn't exist. generally a single file or group of files at a label doesn't make a lot of sense. While it's possible to "scope" labels in TFVC, it's only possible through the commandline.

generally you'd create a label at the repo or branch level at the specified changeset. That will include all files, including the ones you just checked in. Creatign such label is relatively easy from the source control explorer, though you need to copy the changeset number:

[image]

It's unclear to me why you'd only want the changed files to be included in the label, maybe you can elaborate a little more on that requirement.

**Update**: What you desire isn't possible from inside VS and isn't simple from the commandline either. I suppose that with a bit of Powershell Magic against the TFS Client Object Model you can do this from the commandline and it should also be possible to build this as a Visual Studio Extension (or maybe suggest it to the author of the [TFS Source Control Explorer Extensions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8ad891d2-142b-4acf-b487-46db9f3bb5cf).